# How would I find the decimal expansion of $1/99^2$

Tags: fractions, decimal-expansion

I want to find the repeating decimal expansion of $1/99^2$. All I know is that $1/99 = 0.010101\cdots$. How would I continue?

Comment: Why do you think the decimal expansion is repeating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Partial answer**: it's enough find the decimal places for 
$$
\frac{10000}{99^2}=\frac{1}{0.99^2}=\frac{1}{(1-0.01)^2}.
$$
Recall that $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}\approx 1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+5x^4+6x^5+\cdots$, we have (for $x=0.01$)
$$
\frac{10000}{99^2}=1.0203040506070809...
$$
which works out nicely until you get to terms like $100x^{99}$ and above. In any case, this should give you about the first $200$ decimal places for $\frac{1}{99^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for all $x \in (-1,1)$, we have
$$
\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} = 1 + 2x + 3x^2 + 4x^3 + \cdots
$$
Now, let $x = .01$

Comment: When do.I stop? Also I got this far but apparently in the expansion according to the solution 99 comes after 97 why is that? I thought it would be 98

Comment: @VishwaIyer it's a consequence of the carry.  Try adding
$$
9700000000 +\\
98000000+\\
990000+\\
10000 +\\
101
$$

Answer (score 1):

According to Mathematica, $1/99^2$ is

\begin{array}{l}
0. \overline{00010203040506070809101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313} \\
\overline{2333435363738394041424344454647484950515253545556575859606162636465} \\
\overline{666768697071727374757677787980818283848586878889909192939495969799}
\end{array}